# Prove that the lower integral is $\geq 0$ if $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ satisfies $f(x) >0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So here's my proof.  I hope I am heading in the right direction but if not please correct:

Given $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ we have that $f(x)$ are all positive.  The lower integral of $f(x)$ from $a$ to $b$ is the $\sup\{L(f,P): P \text{ is a partition of }[a,b]\}$, with $L(f,P)$ being the lower Darboux sum. And since $L(f,P)= \text{sum of }m_{i} \,x_{i}-x_{i-1}$ with $m_{i}=\inf\{f(x): x \text{ is in }[x_i-1, x_i]\}$ and the $\sup$ of a set of positive numbers is therefore positive.  So the lower integral has to be positive as well.

Comment: Every reasonable estimate of the integral is nonnegative, so the integral must also be nonnegative

Comment: Do you want it to be positive or nonnegative?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct in spirit but has certain ambiguities. Positive means $> 0$ and non-negative means $\geq 0$. You need to change your last statement as "sup of a set of non-negative numbers is non-negative therefore the lower integral has to be non-negative as well.

Answer (score 0):

Pick any partition $P$.

You have $L(f,P) = \sum_i \inf_{x \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]} f(x) (x_i-x_{i-1})$.
Since $f(x) \ge 0$, you have $\inf_{x \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]} f(x) \ge 0$ for
all $i$, hence $L(f,P) \ge 0$.

Since this is true for all partitions $P$, we must have $\sup_{P'} L(f,P') \ge L(f,P) \ge 0$.